# Special soldering requirement

Tags: soldering

I have a special requirement on soldering which I do not know how to achieve. I now need to solder cable to large copper part, which require high solder power.

On the other hand, the temperature of the cable should never exceed 200 degree Celsius. Also, I cannot heat up the whole copper part to achieve melting temperature of solder because of it is fixed to another large object.

Does anyone have a hint to help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sometimes cables and components have alternate, short-term ratings for soldering. A temp of 200C may be an operating temperature maximum.

Comment: spot welding might be more appropriate.

Comment: Does this absolutely need to be soldered, or could you crimp on a cable lug (or ring terminal, for smaller currents) and bolt that down to the large copper part?

Comment: A picture would help.  There are several different soldering techniques that might work but we would need to see what you are dealing with before we can make concrete suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason soldering (vs a mechanical or compression type connection, or a spotweld for that matter) is the only option here?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to make a soldering job like this easier:

- Use a low temperature solder with a melting point less than 200C [like this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kester-solder/24-6040-0027/KE1106-ND/265621). This will also make it easy to solder and stay within the temperature requirements.
- Heat the copper block to a higher than room temperature, 80C or 100C range would be good, this will slow the heat leak into the copper block when trying to solder.

Answer (score 0):

You need a very very big tip. Smaller tips drop in temperature more when transferring heat to a part which means you need to heat them to a higher temperature than the desired soldering temperature. But that means that the as you hold the tip to the part, the temperature will recover and approach that high temperature.

A larger tip drops in temperature by less so you don't need to heat it up as much. An infinitely large tip could be set to exactly 180C and still solder.

It's like heating a room with a tiny amount of 500C air. The cool air in the room dilutes that temperature, but as the room heats up, it will continue to approach 500C.

But you can heat the same room using a large amount of 100C air, and it will never be able to get past 100C.

You might also try using cold spray or some coolant liquid on the wire insulation as you solder.

Or use a very low temperature solder (expensive).

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible using a Metcal soldering station with something like a STTC-117 tip.  The Metcal soldering system is far more efficient at delivering heat to the load than most other soldering systems.

One of the demos I've seen in the past is to solder a penny to a large (5" or 6" square) piece of 1oz copper-clad PCB material.  I personally did something similar: soldering a male DB-25 connector laying front down on a similar piece of copper-clad PCB material.  The Weller and Hakko stations were were using at the time couldn't even touch these operations.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use Resistance Heating to heat the large copper part (photo needed) before attempting to solder the wire to the part.

If this part was a square or rectangular block, making solid connections to the side of the block and using a high-current, low-voltage transformer to supply current into the block.  Think "Spot Welding" transformer.  Use a Variac or other form of power control on the input of the transformer.